# FlowLayoutPanel add to columns?

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel, linklabel

I have a flow layout panel, which i add a Dictionary of Linklables too

Is it possible to add the two to the flow layout panel (as in 2 i mean key and value) next to each other as long as the value.text != "somevalue" in whcih case i want to just add the key to that line.

Here is some sample data and output in the form key and value

```
"Label1" "good stuff"
"Label2" "somevalue"
"Label3" "somevalue"
"Label4" "good stuff"
```

would be displayed as

```
Label1 GoodStuff
Label2
Label3
Label4 GoodStuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) for this one.

Since it supports multiple columns, you can just add Labels (or any other control) on a row for both columns and then hide (set `Visible` to false) the Label on the second column if its content does not match the desired value.

I'd suggest you read about the TableLayoutPanel on MSDN. Here's the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx